# Is it true that probability measures are equal

Tags: measure-theory

I have two Borel probability measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ with support on $\left\{ (x,y) \neq 0 \mid x\geqslant 0, y \geqslant 0 \right\}$ and such that for any $v \geqslant0, w\geqslant 0$ we have
$$
   \int \exp(-xv - yw) \, \mu_1(dx,dy) = \int \exp \left(-xv^{\alpha} - yw^{\alpha} \right) \, \mu_{2}(dx,dy)
$$
for some $\alpha > 0$.  Is it true that $\alpha = 1$ then?

I tried to set $w = 0$ at first. I've obtained an equality
$$
   \int \exp( -xv) \, \nu_1(dx) = \int \exp\left( -xv^{\alpha} \right) \, \nu_2(dx).
$$
It is the equality of Laplace transforms of Borel probability measures: $\mathcal{L}\nu_1 (v) = \mathcal{L} \nu_2 (v^{\alpha})$ and it holds for any $v \geqslant 0$. It isn't possible for $\alpha \neq 1$ if $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are supported in finite number of points by virtue of asymtotics at infinity argument. But how to show this in the case of general probability measures?

Answer (score 0):

Not probability measures but.
$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-xv}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm dx=\Gamma(\alpha)v^{-\alpha}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-xv^\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)\mathrm dx$$

Comment: I don't know, maybe requirement of being a probability measure changes the answer?